# move | copy a file from one docker container to another container with ansible

Tags: python, docker, ansible

I created with ansible 2 containers:

- appOne | python 3.8 | Port: 8082
- appTwo | python 3.8 | Port: 8083

I created a file on appOne that I want to send to appTwo but small challenge, everything must be done via ansible.

I see a lot of tutorials copying from the host machine to a container but nothing from one container to another.

The ansible doc not being intuitive at all for my part, I come to ask for help here...

Do you have a solution for this?
How can I set source and destination?

Comment: Usually you'd use something like an HTTP POST from one container to the other, or use a queueing system like RabbitMQ.  You wouldn't typically "move files", especially since anything you manually transfer will get lost as soon as the destination container is deleted and recreated (on a routine update for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the docker cp API.

```
docker cp CONTAINER:/<some_file> .
```

This commands working for both directions,
(For local to container, and from a container towards local)

So you could use appOne as a "host" destination, and appTwo as a source.

Make sure there is a connection between both of the containers.